# AngularJS - what tools to use in my case - controller or directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I got some data about sports players that I want to print out in `div`s, one for each player, and I'm not sure as to what the right tools for the job are.

What I have now is a container `div` that will hold the new `DOM` elements, and a `controller` attached to it. I stitch the data together in a factory, and pass the API to the controller. Should I pass the data to `$scope` and build the new DOM elements inside the `view` with `ng-repeat`, or should I handle this via a `directive`, and if so, how? Do I have to inject the `factory` object into the directive and go from there?

Comment: The question is : This HTML component is it reusable in others pages ? If yes use a directive. If not : this component is it about DSL (domain specific language) => business visual object ? if yes, use a directive, if not use ng-repeat

Comment: thanks guys, i'll follow your advice

Comment: Here is a great example.

http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/